# EF Core auto migrate missing migrations after app started

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, migration

I develop c# .net 6 API on dev server and migrate some tables.
I need to auto migrate missing migrations on production server when API started.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run `context.Database.Migration()` in your `Program.cs`. Here is an example:

```cs
app.Services.GetRequiredService<ContosoUniversityContext>().Database.Migrate();
```

Full example here:

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using WebApplication2.Models;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ContosoUniversityContext>(
    options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

using (var serviceScope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var services = serviceScope.ServiceProvider;

    var context = services.GetRequiredService<ContosoUniversityContext>();

    await context.Database.MigrateAsync();
}

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```